# MySQL Average of column where there are greater than 5 rows

Tags: mysql, average

Is there any way to use MySQL to only return an average if there are more than X rows?

I am currently using the following query:

```
SELECT round(AVG(a_points),1) as a from points where user_id=X
```

Can this be done in MySQL or do I have to do a row count first then execute this statement?

The table contains

```
user_id     a_points     b_points
```

So a user could have lots of b_points but only 4 a_points and I wouldn't want to average at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will it work for you ?
`SELECT round(AVG(points),1) as a from points where user_id=X HAVING COUNT(*) >5`

Comment: yep, that works for my original post, I missed some details out from what I needed, sorry

Comment: @burtonlazzar: so change to `HAVING COUNT(a_points) > 5` (all records where a_points is null won't count)...

Comment: or `HAVING SUM(a_points) > 5`, whatever makes sense for your data.